# Postgres name search

Tags: postgresql, search, indexing, fuzzy-search, trigram

I have a tiny dataset (~1000 rows). Each row has a username, first name and last name. Can I do a fuzzy search on these three fields by using `pg_trgm` and concatenating the three fields together with two spaces between each? Alternatively, is there a better method to search through this set of users, using trigrams or any other method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select format('%s  %s  %s', username, first_name, last_name)
from t
order by greatest (
    similarity(_name, username),
    similarity(_name, first_name),
    similarity(_name, last_name)
) desc
limit 10
```

or

```
select s
from t, format('%s  %s  %s', username, first_name, last_name) s(s)
order by word_similarity(_name, s) desc
limit 10
```

Comment: Why are there two spaces between `username` and `first_name`, but only one between `first_name` and `last_name`?

Comment: @Shien Just a typo

Comment: More importantly, what happens when the user types in both the first name and username (separated by a space)?

Comment: how would you index this table?